# Java Collections ArrayList, LinkedList cast Exception

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, classcastexception

I found a bizarre case that I can't explain so far.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> a = new LinkedList<>();
    a.add(2);
    a.add(3);
    a.add(4);

    for (ArrayList ax : getBatches(a)){
        System.out.println(ax);
    }

}

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getBatches(List<Integer> optionIds) {
        return new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(optionIds));
}
```

The result of execution is :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

The exception acours in for loop.

The questions is : How? How a method with return type ArrayList< ArrayList< Integer>> can return a LinkedList?

Comment: Your `getBatches` method is returning an `ArrayList`, but this `ArrayList` contains a `LinkedList`. This is the case that's failing in your loop.

Answer (score 5):

Your method returns a raw `ArrayList`, which is why the compiler allows it. However, during runtime, an attempt is made to cast a `LinkedList` (the instance you passed to your `getBatches` method) to an `ArrayList`, leading to `ClassCastException`.

If you changed your method to:

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getBatches(List<Integer> optionIds) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(optionIds));
}
```

you'll get a compilation error.

To avoid both compilation and run-time errors, you'll need to convert the `List` passed to your method to an `ArrayList`:

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getBatches(List<Integer> optionIds) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<>(optionIds)));
}
```

This will return an `ArrayList` whose single element is an `ArrayList` containing the same elements as the `List` passed to the method.

Answer (score 2):

`getBatches()` is returning an ArrayList with generic type `ArrayList<Integer>`. The return type of `Arrays.asList()` is a `List` interface. In order to get from List to ArrayList it's doing an implicit cast. The issue with this is you can't directly cast an ArrayList to a LinkedList.

It's relatively simple to fix this. Instead of iterating through `ArrayList`s, iterate through `List`s. e.g. `for(List l: getBatches(a)`. Then just make `getBatches()` return `ArrayList<List<Integer>>`

In general you'll want to use the most abstracted thing possible. If you don't need implementation specific details of `ArrayList` just call it a List.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of using [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

By calling `new ArrayList(...)` without specifing the generic parameter `T` of `ArrayList<T>` you're using the raw type `ArrayList`.

The above linked docs say:

> But if you assign a raw type to a parameterized type, you get a
>   warning:

Eclipse shows following warning related to `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(optionIds));`:

> Type safety: The expression of type `ArrayList` needs unchecked
>   conversion to conform to `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`

Thus it doesn't result in a compile-time error to return the raw typed `ArrayList` as `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.

The result of `getBatches(a)` is of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`. Elements of this typed list are of type `ArrayList<Integer>`. Assigning them to `ax` using the raw type `ArrayList` is no compile-time error too.

> For backward compatibility, assigning a parameterized type to its raw
>   type is allowed:

But at run-time when it comes to the cast of an element of `getBatches(a)` to `ArrayList` disregarding the warning results in a `ClassCastException` since the run-time type `LinkedList` cannot be casted to `ArrayList` (at this time already with erased generic types).